# Как правильно использовать внешние модули внутри классов в Pyhon?

Tags: python

Как внутри классов инициализировать и начать использовать внешние библиотеки без привязки к их импорту извне.

```
class EEG():

    np = __import__('numpy')
    glob = __import__('glob')
    pd = __import__('pandas')
    os = __import__('os')
    time = __import__('time')

    def pathinfo = np.array()

    dataset = np.array()



    pass
```

Comment: Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Изолированный и самодостаточный класс, который не требует внешних определений

Comment: Да классы и так, в общем-то самодостаточны и не требует, чтобы тот, кто использует класс импортировал его зависимости - они уже импортированы в модуле класса.

Answer (score 2):

[Правильный подход](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) -- импортировать необходимые модули на самом наверху модуля, в котором определён сам класс:

```
import glob
import os
import time

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Если вы думаете вам нужна изоляция кода класса, то просто переместите его в отдельный модуль.